# How to return a set of MarkLogic URIs using cts:triple-range-query()?

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8, triplestore

I have a content repository where the latest versions of documents use an IsLatestVersion triple.

This is an example of a document with the isLatestVersion triple.

```
 Document URI: /Transaction/00000000000101000000/1.xml

 <aptp:Transaction xmlns:aptp="http://sample.com/aptp">
   <aptp:TransactionDate>2016-07-28</aptp:TransactionDate>
   <aptp:TransactionType>Principal</aptp:TransactionType>
   <aptp:Operation>Buy</aptp:Operation>
   <sem:triple name="isLatestVersion"
               xmlns:aptp="http://sample.com/aptp"
               xmlns:sem="http://marklogic.com/semantics">
     <sem:subject datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">
         /Transaction/00000000000101000000/1.xml
     </sem:subject>
     <sem:predicate>isLatestVersion</sem:predicate>
     <sem:object datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#boolean">true</sem:object>
   </sem:triple>
 </aptp:Transaction>
```

I'd like the following code snippet to return the sequence of latest version uris. It currently returns an empty set.

```
import module namespace sem = "http://marklogic.com/semantics" at "/MarkLogic/semantics.xqy";

let $uris :=
  (
    "/Transaction/00000000000101000000/1.xml",
    "/Transaction/00000000000101000001/1.xml",
    "/Transaction/111111/1.xml"
  )

let $query := cts:triple-range-query($uris, "isLatestVersion", fn:true())

return
  cts:uris("", (), $query)
```

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: I see that I just need to add the sem:iri("isLatestVersion") to the query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few thoughts:

- Consider omitting $uris in the `cts:triple-range-query`. You can pass in empty sequence instead.
- You likely need to wrap `"isLatestVersion"` in `sem:iri`, e.g. `sem:iri("isLatestVersion")`.
- Make sure triple index is enabled, though I think it would have complained if you didn't.

HTH!

Answer (score 3):

This code snippet works well.

```
declare function local:getLatestUris($uris)
{
  let $query := cts:triple-range-query($uris, sem:iri("isLatestVersion"), fn:true())

  return cts:uris((), (), $query)                
};

local:getLatestUris((
    "/Transaction/00000000000101000000/1.xml",
    "/Transaction/00000000000101000001/1.xml",
    "/Transaction/111111/1.xml"
))
```